# Paging not working in my Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I'm working on a grid currently that has an issue with paging.  The grid fills up to the point it has 15 items within it.  That is the Page Size max, however, pages are not added beyond that.  I'm not entirely sure why it does not add pages.  Below is my code.

View

```
var gridPageSize = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<Nop.Core.Domain.Common.AdminAreaSettings>().GridPageSize;
    <table class="adminContent">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(Html.Telerik().Grid<CategoryModel.CategoryUnitsModel>()
                    .Name("categoryunits-grid")
                    .DataKeys(keys =>
                    {
                        keys.Add(x => x.Id);
                        keys.Add(x => x.CategoryId);
                        keys.Add(x => x.UnitId);
                    })
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                    {
                        dataBinding.Ajax()
                            .Select("CategoryUnitsList", "Category", new { categoryId = Model.Id })
                            .Insert("CategoryUnitsInsert", "Category", new { categoryId = Model.Id })
                            .Update("CategoryUnitsInsert", "Category", new { categoryId = Model.Id })
                            .Delete("CategoryUnitsDelete", "Category", new { categoryId = Model.Id });
                    })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(x => x.UnitId)
                            .Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(x => x.UnitText);
                        columns.Command(commands =>
                        {
                            commands.Edit();
                            commands.Delete();
                        })
                        .Width(100);
                    })
                    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
                    .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound"))
                    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnEdit("onEdit"))
                    .EnableCustomBinding(true))

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function onRowDataBound(e) {
                        $(e.row).find('a.t-grid-edit').remove(); //remove Delete button
                    }

                    function onEdit(e) {
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadAvailableUnits", "Category")', { categoryId: $("#Id").val() }, function (data) {
                            var ddl = $("#UnitText").data("tDropDownList");
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                ddl.dataBind(data);
                                ddl.reload();
                            }
                            else {
                                $('a[class="t-button t-grid-cancel"]').click();
                                alert("There are no Units left to select from");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

EditorTemplates\CategoryUnit

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("UnitText")
```

Model (CategoryModel.CategoryUnitsModel)

```
public partial class CategoryUnitsModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Units.Fields.UnitText")]
        [UIHint("CategoryUnit")]
        public string UnitText { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost, GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult CategoryUnitsList(GridCommand command, int categoryId)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        var categoryUnits = _unitsService.GetCategoryUnits(categoryId, command.Page - 1, command.PageSize);
        var categoryUnitsModel = PrepareCategoryUnitsModel(categoryUnits);

        var model = new GridModel<CategoryModel.CategoryUnitsModel>
        {
            Data = categoryUnitsModel,
            Total = categoryUnitsModel.Count
        };

        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = model
        };
    }

    public JsonResult LoadAvailableUnits(int categoryId)
    {
        var categoryUnits = _unitsService.GetAvailableUnits(categoryId);
        var categoryUnitsModel = PrepareAvailableUnitsInModel(categoryUnits);
        var returnData = new SelectList(categoryUnitsModel, "UnitId", "UnitText");
        return Json(returnData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult CategoryUnitsInsert(GridCommand command, CategoryModel.CategoryUnitsModel model)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        var searchForEntry = _unitsService.GetCategoryUnitByCategoryIdAndUnitId(model.CategoryId, Int32.Parse(model.UnitText));
        if (searchForEntry != null)
        {
            return CategoryUnitsList(command, model.CategoryId);
        }

        var categoryUnit = new CategoryUnits
        {
            UnitId = Int32.Parse(model.UnitText),
            CategoryId = model.CategoryId
        };

        _unitsService.InsertCategoryUnit(categoryUnit);

        return CategoryUnitsList(command, model.CategoryId);
    }

    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult CategoryUnitsDelete(GridCommand command, CategoryModel.CategoryUnitsModel model, int id)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        var categoryId = model.CategoryId;
        _unitsService.DeleteCategoryUnit(model.CategoryId, id);

        return CategoryUnitsList(command, categoryId);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks all.

Kindest Regards,
Chad Johnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out the issue.  In my Controller, when I set the Total when binding the grid, I was using the count of the data that had been bound to the Model instead of the total count that my Entity brought back.

Comment: i am also having the issue. can you explain more on this

Comment: Sure.  What was happening (as I recall) was when I did my call to Entity, I would get a list of items back.  I would then merge my DB Model into a UI Model for the page.  The difference was my UI Model had a different count than what was in the DB Model due that I wasn't using the total count I had from the DB Model.  I started passing the total count from the DB Model over to the UI Model, which fixed my issue.  Hope this helps.